# How to open context menu on longclick on viewpage image in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, contextmenu

I am new in android and `developing wallpaper application`. I create a page using `view-pager` where all `wallpaper slides one by one.`

Now, I have to `open context menu` when user `long-press on any one image`. I tried many times and also search but not found anywhere.

Below code used:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

registerForContextMenu(viewPager);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Picture Options");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Set Picture as");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");

}
```

## Adapter code

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GridViewDemo.mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        return new Fragment() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(FullImageView.this);
                imageView.setImageResource(GridViewDemo.mThumbIds[position]);
                return imageView;
                }
            };
        }
}
```

Let me know if any have experience in it.

Thanks

Comment: use registerForContextMenu(your image instance here);

Comment: I used registerForContextMenu(viewpager) above code.

Comment: ur implemented in wrong way,you need to give for image view in getview of your viewpager adapter.

Comment: Can you please give me some code sentences which you told me. I am new in it so some confused. Thanks.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: I updated my question with adapter code. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81176/discussion-between-harsh4u-and-ram).

Answer (score 0):

Is a long click listener a good solution for you ?

```
   imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //your code 
        return true;
    }
});
```